# 19C upgrade + framework 4.6.2

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2008, .net-4.6.2, oracle18c

I have two applications developed in C# .NET framework 4.6.2 that attacks against an Oracle 10g Database, now planning to upgrade the database to an Oracle 19c. One of the applications is a web application and the other is a desktop application. At this moment I am using Oracle.DataAccess.dll and it is working properly. Will my applications keep working properly after the upgrade or should I recompile my applications with another dll? Or what other configurations required for C# application?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Oracle.DataAccess are you using? The answer depends on it. Are you getting the ODP.NET driver via NuGet?

In theory a 11.2.0.3 client should be able to connect to a 19 database.

Personally, I would ensure that the client driver is at least of version 12.2.